# Grid not populating data from WebAPI in Angular data grid

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm new at angular, and implementing a basic data grid which takes data from an API. The data is being logged in the console, but when I pass it as row data in the grid, it does not populate there.

If I pass the same data as a const array, it is displayed perfectly.

Below is my component.ts:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { SkyAgGridService, SkyCellType } from '@skyux/ag-grid';
import { Student } from 'src/app/models/student.model';
import { StudentsService } from 'src/app/services/students.service';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';


import {
  ColDef,
  GridApi,
  GridOptions,
  GridReadyEvent,
  ValueFormatterParams,
} from 'ag-grid-community';

import { SKY_AG_GRID_DEMO_DATA } from './basic-data-grid-docs-demo-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-basic-data-grid-docs-demo',
  templateUrl: './basic-data-grid-docs-demo.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class SkyBasicDataGridDemoComponent implements OnInit{

  students: Student[] = [];
  

  

  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
      field: 'FirstMidName',
      headerName: 'Name',
    },
    {
      field: 'LastName',
      headerName: 'Last Name',
    },
    {
      field: 'Gender',
      headerName: 'Gender'
    },
    {
      field: 'EnrollmentDate',
      headerName: 'Enrollment date',
      type: SkyCellType.Date,
    },
    
  ];

  public gridApi: GridApi | undefined;
  public gridData: any[] = SKY_AG_GRID_DEMO_DATA; // if the same data is passed as a const, it is populated
  public gridOptions: GridOptions;
  public searchText = '';
  public getStudentsSubscription: Subscription | undefined;
  

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.studentsService.getAllStudents()
    .subscribe({
      next: (students) => {
        this.students= students;
        console.log("this is students", students);
        
        console.log(this.gridData);
      },
      error: (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  }

  constructor(private agGridService: SkyAgGridService, private studentsService: StudentsService) {
      this.gridOptions = {
      columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
     onGridReady: (gridReadyEvent): void => this.onGridReady(gridReadyEvent),
     rowSelection: 'single',
    };
    this.gridOptions = this.agGridService.getGridOptions({
      gridOptions: this.gridOptions,
    });
  }

  public onGridReady(gridReadyEvent: GridReadyEvent): void {
    this.gridApi = gridReadyEvent.api;
    this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
    
  }
```

Below is the component.html:

```
<div>
    <sky-ag-grid-wrapper>
      <ag-grid-angular [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [rowData]="students">
      </ag-grid-angular>
    </sky-ag-grid-wrapper>
</div>
```

Below is the service for API call:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Student } from '../models/student.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentsService {
  baseApiUrl: string = environment.baseApiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllStudents(): Observable<Student[]>{
      return this.http.get<Student[]>(this.baseApiUrl + 'api/student');
  }
}
```

Below is the model:

```
export interface Student{
    ID: number;
    FirstMidName: string;
    LastName: string;
    Gender: string;
    EnrollmentDate: Date;
}
```

Here's the sample data which displays the grid perfectly:

```
export const SKY_AG_GRID_DEMO_DATA = [
    {ID:2,
    FirstMidName:"John333",
    LastName:"Doe222",
    Gender:"Male",
    EnrollmentDate:"2022-12-26T00:00:00"},
    {ID:3,
    FirstMidName :"John2",
    LastName:"Doe2",
    Gender:"Male",
    EnrollmentDate:"2022-12-21T00:00:00"},
    {ID:4,
    FirstMidName:"Lois",
    LastName:"Lane",
    Gender:"Female",
    EnrollmentDate:"2023-01-12T00:00:00"}
  ];
```

Comment: did you try `setRowData`?

Comment: Tried using this.gridApi.setRowData(this.students); in the OnGridReady method.
Data is populated, but vanishes on page reload.

Comment: Please could you put together a stackblitz or similar that demonstrates the issue?  It's usually easiest to get an ag-grid example from their website and alter it until it shows the issue you are having